# MYSQL - insert into table or update if anything is different

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okey, so im trying to store the logged in facebook user´s friends list into a MYSQL table.

Im storing the logged in user data: ID and Name;
And am storing the logged in user friends list: ID and Name;

So the table looks like this:

```
['facebook_user_id']  ['facebook_user_name'] ['facebook_friend_id']  ['facebook_friend_name']
123123123123            User1                  23424234234234          User 20
231321231231            User2                  23424234234234          User 20
```

So you can see that user1 and user2 has the same friend and if user friend 'User 20' change his/her name I need to update the information, but only for the logged in user, so if user1 logs in the effect will only effect him/her.

But if user1 gets a new friend I need to insert the new friend and update if theres any changes.

How should I do this with PHP? I have seen something similar but didnt work that well for me.

```
    INSERT INTO table (facebook_user_id, facebook_user_name, facebook_friend_id, facebook_friend_name) 
VALUES ('facebook_user_id' (to short it down) .....)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (facebook_user_id=facebook_user_id (and for every entry)....)
```

Thanks in advance, and any pointers will help me out alot.

Comment: Please post your table scheme (what constraints are there?).

Comment: Could you explain why `ON DUPLICATE KEY` did not work that well for you? What happened? (And you _do_ have a `UNIQUE` on some column?)

Comment: Well I don´t have any UNIQUE in my table, its pretty straight forward. its only int and varchar. nothing more or less. Well the first time I tried it, it inputed like 170 entries and when without doing anything and running the script again it added just more and more entries. And with more testing and fixing my script, now nothing happends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you meant.
I am trying to save **user `A`** Facebook friends into a table.
When someone logs in with Facebook I am storing, their name and Facebook id. As well as their friends, Facebook id and name.

This is how I would do it. Here is my solution if you need generated schema code let me know.

-**Create three tables:** registered users, buddies, lookup table

**table 1:** registered users

```
[id, userId, facebookUid]
```

**table 2:** buddies

```
[id, buddyid, buddy name]
```

**table 3:** You need a lookup table.

```
[id, userId, buddyid]
```

**Steps:**

1. When `UserA` logs in with Facebook, save their buddies into the `buddies` table
2. This approach above you don't have to worry about duplicate names. If someone updates their name, it will be changed across the board.
3. You can use [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to find who has buddies in common.

Comment: Hey @James, thanks for the tip! This looks like a much better solution for my question! :) Now, I just need to find the solution for remove if the facebook friend as deleted the user

Comment: @MariusDjerv you could add field in the table call last_updated. If the  data wasn't updated with in a month or so you could import/refresh their friends list.